# ConcurrentModificationException thrown on iterator.remove

Tags: java

I'm getting a ConcurrentModificationException despite using the iterator to perform the remove operation. Any ideas as to why?

```
for (Iterator<Thread> iter = threads.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Thread hook = iter.next();
        if(someCondition){
                iter.remove();
        }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that another thread is messing with the `threads` list. Some thread may for instance be appending something on the list?

Comment: aren't you also modifying at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a modification concurrent to using an Iterator, which is not supported. Either iterate a list clone, or use a CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Or memory what to remove in a new list, and call list.removeAll(whatIWantedToRemove) afterwards.

Comment: *a modification concurrent to using an Iterator* Should be ok as long as the modification is done through the iterator as described by the OP.

Comment: A list clone can suffer from the same problem because to create the clone it iterates the original list. However, I think this might be the safest approach.

Answer (score 2):

From JavaDoc [Iterator.remove()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29):

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by
>   the iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once
>   per call to next. The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the
>   underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress
>   in any way other than by calling this method.

It seem that the behavior is depended to the collection. Also as `aioobe` pointed out. I can reproduce `ConcurrentModificationException` when I modify the collection somewhere else. Using only `Iterator` interface, I can only reproduce `IllegalStateException`.